# How to modify twitter bootstrap ".icon-bar" colors

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, less

Theres a button that appears in bootstrap when the viewport is narrow .. using bootstrap-responsive ...

How do I change the color appearance of this button? I know the folks at bootswatch.com are able to do it by changing some vars in less but how are they doing it?

EDIT: I made a little progress with the following SASS code. (im using sass-bootstrap gem)

```
.navbar .btn-navbar {
  background-color: $navbarLinkBackgroundHover;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
     -moz-border-radius: 4px;
          border-radius: 4px;

          &:hover {
            background-color: lighten($navbarLinkBackgroundHover, 1%);
          }
}
```

The above changes the background of my button and the roundness of the button.. I still cant figure out how to change the border stroke? any ideas?

```
.navbar .btn-navbar .icon-bar {
  background-color: $heading-blue;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
     -moz-border-radius: 4px;
          border-radius: 4px;
}
```

Now this chunk of code helps me change the color of the horizontal dashes within the button!

EDIT2:

Figured out the border-stroke .. its called border-color and border-width in css! (applied to .navbar .btn-navbar)

```
  border-color: $dropdown-border $dropdown-border darken($dropdown-border, 10%) $dropdown-border;
  border-width: 2px;
```

Comment: Please provide some example of said button. I'm very familiar with Bootstrap, but don't recall the button. http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#responsive

Comment: This is the button that appears on the right side of navbar when the browser is resized to be smaller. Its a little button with three horizontal lines that serves as a menu of sorts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.navbar .btn-navbar {
display: none;
float: right;
padding: 7px 10px;
margin-left: 5px;
margin-right: 5px;
color: #ffffff;
text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
background-color: #ededed;
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #f2f2f2, #e5e5e5);
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#f2f2f2), to(#e5e5e5));
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f2f2f2, #e5e5e5);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #f2f2f2, #e5e5e5);
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #f2f2f2, #e5e5e5);
background-repeat: repeat-x;
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#fff2f2f2', endColorstr='#ffe5e5e5', GradientType=0);
border-color: #e5e5e5 #e5e5e5 #bfbfbf;
border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
*background-color: #e5e5e5;
/* Darken IE7 buttons by default so they stand out more given they won't have borders */
```

This is the CSS selector with attributes.  You can just create a new CSS rule to overwrite these values without changing the less variables.

If you are wondering how the less variables work, they create gradients based on variable values.  For example,

```
box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
```

creates a box-shadow from a color 75% lighter than black.  The variable 0, 0, 0 was passed to the box-shadow property.

Comment: the following sass code i wrote up just now references exactly the same css selector you mentioned! thanks for that..

Comment: .navbar .btn-navbar {
  background-color: $navbarLinkBackgroundHover;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
     -moz-border-radius: 4px;
          border-radius: 4px;
    
    &:hover {
     background-color: lighten($navbarLinkBackgroundHover, 1%);
    }
}

Answer (score -1):

why not simply ovveride them with `style = "background-color:#hex;"`.
Useful if yo